# Underline/strikethrough text in HTML Java

Tags: java, html

I'm trying to see if there is a difference between making the text you entering to be underlined or struck through and the text you already enter to make it this way.

I'm working with Java and HTML.

In the Android Studio I can see that the HTML being written to the JTextPane is something like this:

```
<body>
    <strike></strike>
</body>
```

but trying to type an 'a', does not produce a struck through 'a' symbol.

However, trying to type 'a', select it and then make it a strikethrough works as expected.

I'm checking for the presence of the HTML.Tag.S style in the HTML in order to see if the strikethrough is present or not in addition to the `<strike>` tag.

Also, if I refresh the window the text appears as it should, i.e. struck.

Changing the style of the font to become 'bold' also works as expected from the first time regardless if I select the existing text or I select the 'bold' and start typing the text.

Does anyone have an idea where should I look?